# C# Signal Processing Plotting Rapid Data

Tags: c#, plot, signal-processing, zedgraph, data-processing

I have a circuit that sends me two different data from sensors. Data is coming as packets. First data is '$' to separate one packet to another. After '$' it sends 16 bytes microphone data and 1 byte pulse sensor data. I have an array to store incoming data and after plotting the data in each 20 ms, i start to write new bytes from zero index of array. I need to plot these data to different graphs using ZedGraph. However i could not separate those data correctly. Sometimes one or more data of audio are shown in other graph. Here is my code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (data[i * 18] == Convert.ToByte('$'))
            {
                for (int x = ((i * 18) + 1); x < ((i * 18) + 17); x++)
                {
                    listAuido.Add(time, data[x]);
                }
                for (int a = ((i * 18) + 17); a < ((i * 18) + 18); a++)
                {
                    listPulse.Add(time, data[a]);
                }
            }
        }
```

How can i solve this issue?

Circuit settings: BaudRate: 38400, Frequency: 200hz, CommunicationType: RS232.

Port Settings:ReadTimeOut=5 WrtieTimeOut=5;

While reading data i am using codes below. Read_Data1 refers data[] the code above. I have a counter and after plotting the data its value equals zero and i prevent my buffer `index out of range exception`

```
    byte[] Read_Data1 = new byte[1000];
    private void myPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!myPort.IsOpen)
            return;
        if (myPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[myPort.BytesToRead];
            myPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            DataConversion.bytetobyte(Read_Data1, buffer, buffer.Length, count);
            count += buffer.Length;
            DataRecord.SaveBytesToFile(buffer, save.FileName);
        }
    }

    public static void bytetobyte(byte[] Storage, byte[] databyte, int datacount, int count)
    {
        int abc;
        for (abc = 0; abc < datacount; abc++)
        {
            Storage[abc + count] = databyte[abc];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data stream its hard to understand exactly what's going on but when you multiply by 18 the offset will be different as i increases. in order for that to work you need to be sure that exactly 4 packets are actually in the buffer at this time or things might get weird. Having worked a far bit with rs232 connected measurement hardware I often find that their software is not all that consistent, so I'd be careful about assuming the data is there :)

Look into how and when you're reading data into the `data` buffer, are you sure it contains fresh data everytime you call your code?

The loop looks correct but its a little difficult to read, I'd rewrite it as

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (data[i * 18] == Convert.ToByte('$'))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
            {
                listAuido.Add(time, data[(i * 18) +1 + x]);
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) // this doesn't really need to be a loop
            {
                listPulse.Add(time, data[ ((i * 18) + 17)+ a]);
            }
        }
```

---

I looked at the code you added but its not immediately clear how the first bit of code is called by the second. I still think that there is something with the buffer handling that is causing your issue, but you could possibly eliminate that but using the buffer built into the serial port and just one byte at the time:

```
while(true){  //you could do this on a separate thread or on a timer
    if(port.ReadByte() == Convert.ToByte('$')){
        for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
            listAuido.Add(time, port.ReadByte());
        listPulse.Add(time, port.ReadByte());
    }
}
```

Comment: Frequency is 200 hz so 1second/200hz = 5ms. Data is coming in each 5ms but i plot the data each 20 ms. So i think there must be a drift. Also when i put some break points the buffer size looks greater than the packet size.

Comment: Its hard to comment on that without seeing how you read the data, but the port will buffer all the data that comes into it

Comment: Thx for the simplification of my code. I edited my code to show how i am reading the data. I would be happy if you can have a look of it.